# What happens when a digital signal reaches a receiving integrated circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, circuits

This might sound overly simple, but I've never seen a good explanation for this.

What happens when a digital signal (I2C, SPI, USB, or whatever else) reaches its destination and is "read" by the receiving integrated circuit?

**QUESTION 1:**

I've read that the integrated circuit samples the signal at its clock rate, kind of like an ADC will sample an analog signal. If the signal is high enough to drive the receiving buffer into saturation, then the signal will be read as a "1", otherwise it is undefined or 0. Is this correct? **I hate to have to say this, but I would like it if commenters would state "Yes" or "No" as to whether or not this is correct.**

If that is correct, then that would mean that all digital integrated circuits have a Nyquist frequency. Is this also correct, or am I overgeneralizing? **I hate to have to say this AGAIN, but I would like it if commenters would state "Yes" or "No" as to whether or not this is correct.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: But if the answer to first question is "No" (which it is because digital inputs are not sampled like how ADC samples an analog input), it means that there is no answer to your second question as answer to first was not "yes".

Comment: Your question cannot be properly answered as written. You need to define your digital signal, with such things as driver type, rise and fall times, frequency, voltage, etc. You state integrated circuit, there are probably millions of them and a lot of different families. There will be reflections etc again dependent on signal transport media, and connections.

Comment: @Justme well obviously...

Comment: @Gil I understand that the signal transition depends on many factors and that the input on an integrated circuit does not literally work like a 1-bit ADC. I'm looking at this in terms of inherent band limiting in a digital channel. Load capacitance is one limiting factor, losses are another, rise time will determine the power spectrum... but in thinking about the effect of sampling in terms of band-limiting, one would expect sample rate also determines the power spectrum that is used to "read" a signal that carries digital data. In PAM-4, there is a Nyquist. I'm just trying to generalize.

Answer (score 2):

For a clock-synchronous digital signal, the receiving end is typically a clocked flip-flop, or a device that samples from the continuous-time domain to a discrete-time domain. While this *technically* allows us to discuss a Nyquist frequency, it's easier to just think of a baseband digital signal that we have to sample at its clock rate (or oversample).

This is preceded (conceptually) by a simple (one-bit) analog-to-digital converter -- in the case of I2C or SPI, it's simply a CMOS input buffer -- if the signal is within the datasheet's low/high valid input voltage range, the output is 0/1 respectively; otherwise it's unspecified.

For a differential signal like USB, the one-bit "ADC" a fast analog comparator -- 1 if D+ is greater than D-, 0 otherwise.

Note that not all digital signals are clock-synchronous; some are self-clocking and their timing is recovered using a clock recovery circuit at the receiver. While this is still discrete-time sampling, it's signal-dependent in a way that makes it difficult to apply ideas like Nyquist frequency.

Comment: It sounds like the answer to the first question I asked is "yes", so my interpretation of reading a digital signal as a 1-bit ADC is correct. The second point I asked is not really correct in the same way we like to think of sampling a sine wave (for example). Am I reading your response accurately?

Comment: @sparaps that's an accurate reading but it's it's still not a highly useful one. The kind of modeling you would do for this really depends on what useful engineering goal you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I understand that the signal transition depends on many factors and that the input on an integrated circuit does not literally work like a 1-bit ADC. I'm looking at this in terms of inherent band limiting in a digital channel. Load capacitance is one limiting factor, losses are another, rise time will determine the power spectrum... but in thinking about the effect of sampling in terms of band-limiting, one would expect sample also determines the power spectrum that is used to "read" a signal that carries digital data. In PAM-4, there is a Nyquist, so I'm trying to generalize.

Answer (score 2):

## (TL;DR)

> I've read that the integrated circuit samples the signal at its clock
> rate, kind of like an ADC will sample an analog signal. If the signal
> is high enough to drive the receiving buffer into saturation, then the
> signal will be read as a "1", otherwise it is undefined or 0. Is this
> correct?

Yes

> If that is correct, then that would mean that all digital integrated
> circuits have a Nyquist frequency. Is this also correct, or am I
> overgeneralizing?

Yes, *technically,* but see below.

## Details

Digital design is all about creating *noise immunity* by discarding parts of the analog signal. In analog systems, noise is "always" uncorrelated and thus noise always "adds". Digital processing ignores analog signal effects that are below certain thresholds, preventing each stage from accumulating more noise. Once the signal is in the digital domain, we can stack up as many stages of logic as we need. So to keep things simple, the digital-to-analog boundary is usually modeled by considering a single flip-flop.

Analog voltage noise below the *noise margin* \$VIH_{min} - VIL_{max}\$ is discarded, as the signal is amplified to saturation internally for logic high or logic low value. Effectively there's a comparator with a threshold voltage guaranteed to be somewhere between \$VIH_{min}\$ and \$VIL_{max}\$, under all operating temperatures and manufacturing variations.

Timing jitter is also discarded, as long as the signal is stable during the specified *setup and hold time* before and after the active clock edge. This is what defines the sampling aperture. The input signal can change anytime outside of this time interval. It is valid to think of this as "samples the signal at its clock rate" as you say.

The price we pay for this noise immunity is that we have to accept a certain amount of quantization noise when an analog signal is digitized, we cannot magically "DSP away" anything much below the quantization noise floor, unless we know something else about the signal besides what was actually measured. And the price for eliminating timing jitter is that we must accept that there is a minimum timing increment that the digital system can use.

There's a dragon in the mix, called *metastability*, where an analog signal just barely sneaks past the digital rules (by changing during the setup/hold time interval, or by changing very slowly near the digital VIH/VIL threshold), and this unfortunate analog input puts the digital input into an indeterminate state for an indeterminate amount of time.

It's very unconventional to think of a digital input in the frequency domain as though it was a delta-sigma ADC input. Most analysis considers the digital input in terms of its DC levels and its timing margin. The only frequency-domain signal of interest is the system clock itself, and even there we're normally only interested in determining how fast we can push the digital logic, i.e. what is the maximum worst-case propagation delay through the combinational logic.

Nyquist frequency (below which there is no frequency aliasing) is a useful concept in Analog to Digital Converters, because any power at frequencies above Nyquist are aliased into the Nyquist/2 baseband. Usually when making analog measurements with an ADC we want to use an analog low-pass filter before the ADC input to prevent unwanted higher-frequency power from contaminating the signal of interest. (Radar systems are an exception.)

If you think of a flip-flop as a 1-bit ADC, then its Nyquist frequency would seem to be half the clock rate... except it's more complicated than that. A typical finite state machine or FSM is synchronous logic built out of a set of flip-flops together with some combinational logic that determines the next state. During each clock cycle, the flip-flop captures the "next state" value from the combinational logic, and updates its output. The output feeds back through the combinational logic, which has some propagation delay. Considering the worst-case propagation delay through the combinational logic, together with the flip-flop's setup and hold times, is what determines the maximum clock rate that the FSM can support. Usually the clock is allowed to be slower, even practically a DC level (unless dynamic logic was used). If the system is operated at a clock rate that is too fast, it won't work. The actual Nyquist limit of the non-aliased bandwidth of the flip-flop's input, will depend on the setup + hold period as well as the repetition rate. But since the digital inputs cannot be sampled faster than the system clock, and the system clock speed is limited by propagation delay and setup and hold time, I don't see the value of trying to apply Nyquist limit here.

The only type of situation where there could conceivably be significant power on the digital inputs, above their Nyquist aliasing frequency, would actually be considered as part of EMC "radiated emission" or "radiated interference" prevention, and it's addressed in terms of preventing that power from getting into the vulnerable hardware nodes. Nyquist just isn't very important in this case, EMC compliance is about making the system robust against all kinds of external aggressors.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

> I've read that the integrated circuit samples the signal at its clock rate, kind of like an ADC will sample an analog signal. If the signal is high enough to drive the receiving buffer into saturation, then the signal will be read as a "1", otherwise it is undefined or 0. Is this correct?

Please, if you say "I have read..." add a reference where you have found the information because context matters. For the same reason you won't get a yes/no answer.

Answer:
In general: **no**; simply because it is not true that *all* digital inputs are sampled by a clock signal.
Example: a clock signal is also a digital input.
So it can't be clocked (unless there is another clock signal for sampling the first clock signal but then the same applies to the second clock signal etc.). Also other signals may *not* be sampled by a clock.

For the special case of *synchonous* signals (= sampled by a clock signal): **yes**.

Comment: Sure I understand that not all digital interfaces use a clock. I was thinking of any signal with an embedded or source-synchronous clock, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1:

Often, but not always. Some protocols have no clock in them, such as RS232. With those protocols, the receiver must sample the signal at a high rate to determine where the data bits start and end.

But there are protocols that carry a clock, including ones that use data/strobe signalling. On those, there is no need to over sample. The clock tells you when to read the data.

Part 2:

If it's a protocol that needs over sampling, then ideally sample at something like 8 or 16 times the data rate. 4 times should also work.

But 2 times might work if the signal transitions (high to low, or low to high) are sufficiently clean.  Less than that won't work.

So there is a "Nyquist rate" to consider.

Comment: 1. Sure I understand that, I was thinking something with an embedded clock or a source-synchronous clock.

With Nyquist, I'm trying to relate what happens in a typical digital bistream to a protocol like PAM-4, which is sampled at a specific rate and does have a Nyquist frequency in the conventional sense.

Comment: There is at least one UART that re-synchronizes on each edge, the MC68901. I watched it receiving perfectly with odd baudrates. =-O

Answer (score 0):

*Is it correct that digital inputs sample an analog signal like an ADC will?*

Yes.

It is commonly a 1-bit "converter", often with hysteresis. But hey, the output signal of the input's first stage is still an analog signal like the input signal. Hm...

*If that is correct, then that would mean that all digital integrated circuits have a Nyquist frequency.*

Yes.

The wire with the data is sampled at the frequency of the clock on its line (at least with I²C and SPI). So if its signal changes faster than the clock rate, the received signal will be aliased... **if** the information were in the frequency. But it is not, so I don't see any application of the term "Nyquist frequency" on such transmission protocols.

Comment: Great, thank you for clarifying